# Mule Transform Message Filtering Issue

Tags: mule

Using mulesoft to integrate supplier information changes between systems. A supplier can have one to many sites. Some supplier criteria, as well as some supplier site criteria must be met for one particular system to care about the update. I have a transform message that sets a flag to 'True' or 'False' based on the evaluation of the criteria, which in turn tells us whether or not to send the data to a particular system. Here is my dataweave for setting the flag...

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java

//Function to determine if site is future site 
%function isFutureSite(siteCode) 'Y' when siteCode contains 'FUTURE' otherwise 'N'

//Function to determine if vendor is a dummy vendor
%function isDummyVendor(vendorName) 'Y' when vendorName contains 'Dummy' otherwise 'N'
---
//Set processFlag to True or False to determine whether or not to send updates to WMS based on vendor and site attributes
using (crit=payload.MMAP_SUPPLIER_DETAILS_OBJ_TYPE) { 
(crit.SITES filter ($.ORG_ID == '116' and $.PURCHASING_SITE_FLAG == 'Y' and $.INACTIVE_DATE == ''
                     and isFutureSite($.VENDOR_SITE_CODE) == 'N' and $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0 to 2] == 'P&A'
                    ) map {
    Process: 'True'} 
 when crit.SUPPLIER.END_DATE_ACTIVE == '' 
  and isDummyVendor(crit.SUPPLIER.VENDOR_NAME) == 'N'
  and (crit.SUPPLIER.VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE == 'PRODUCTION' or crit.SUPPLIER.VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE == 'COMMON')
 otherwise Process: 'False')}
```

First I filter the supplier sites on the 5 criteria specified within crit.SITES filter. There will always be 0 or 1 site for a supplier that meets all of those 5 criteria. I then filter on the supplier criteria (3 conditions based on supplier level data). 
Everything is fine when ...
1.) all criteria is met (3 supplier conditions are true and there is a site for the supplier that meets all 5 site criteria. I then get a true value for the Process flag {Process=True}, or 2.) there is a site for the supplier that meets all 5 site criteria, but not all 3 of the supplier conditions are met. I then get a false value of the Process flag {Process=False}.

The issue I am having is when there is a supplier that has 0 sites that meet all 5 of the site criteria (crit.SITES filter returns no sites). I then get nothing for the flag {}.

How can I get a value (False) set to the flag in this case?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by also adding the filter to the conditions within the mapping (above the last line, otherwise...), checking that it doesn't return an empty array, like so...

    
and (crit.SITES filter ($.ORG_ID == '116' and $.PURCHASING_SITE_FLAG == 'Y' and $.INACTIVE_DATE == ''
             and isFutureSite($.VENDOR_SITE_CODE) == 'N' and $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0 to 2] == 'P&A'
               )) != []
 otherwise Process: 'False')}

Comment: Actually not... the above mentioned resolution did not resolve it... all flags get set to False.

Comment: Sorry to go back-and-forth here, but the first comment actually DID resolve the issue. I had forgotten to go back and change my 'using' statement to use the incoming flowVar that was actually being passed in, instead of using payload, which I had switched in order to test against some sample data.